# Looking for MCU with AES. Migrating from STM32F107

Tags: arm, migration, aes, microcontroller, cortex-m

I'm looking for Microcontrollers based on the ARM Cortex-M3. The MCU should have an AES Accelerator, SPI, (at least 3) USARTs, USB OTG. I'm migrating from STM32F107 (the reason I'm migrating is because I need the AES by hardware) any good recommendations that will save me time in the migration process? I've been looking in the ST and ATMEL website, but I haven't found one that have the characteristics I need.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- [LPC18xx](http://beta.nxp.com/products/microcontrollers/cortex_m3/lpc1800/#products) from NXP (doesn't seem
  to be generally available yet). They
  also announced LPC4000 series based
  on Cortex-M4.
- [EFM32](http://www.energymicro.com/products/efm32-gecko-microcontroller-family) from EnergyMicro.
- [STM32F215/217](http://www.st.com/internet/com/press_release/p3029.jsp) from ST seem to
  have an encryption module.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think I'll go with the STM32F217

Answer (score 4):

**EFM32 Leopard Gecko**

http://www.energymicro.com/products/efm32lg995f64-efm32lg995f128-efm32lg995f256

- From 64 - 256 kilobytes of Flash
- Hardware AES with 128/256-bit keys in 54/75 cycles
- UART/SPI/SmartCard (ISO 7816)/IrDA/I2S
- 3× Universal Synchronous/Asynchronous Receiver/Transmitter
- Universal Serial Bus (USB) with Host and OTG support (Fully USB 2.0 compliant, On-chip PHY and embedded 5V to 3.3V regulator)

**EFM32 Giant Gecko**

http://www.energymicro.com/products/efm32gg995f512-efm32gg995f1024

- Up to 1 megabyte of Flash
- Hardware AES with 128/256-bit keys in 54/75 cycles
- UART/SPI/SmartCard (ISO 7816)/IrDA/I2S
- 3× Universal Synchronous/Asynchronous Receiver/Transmitter
- Universal Serial Bus (USB) with Host and OTG support (Fully USB 2.0 compliant, On-chip PHY and embedded 5V to 3.3V regulator)